# How to connect spring data elasticsearch 3.6 with elasticsearch version 8.5 with security settings enabled?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a fresh install of elasticsearch 8.5 with security enabled by default. I want to connect my spring boot application with elasticsearch, i have configured my application.properties to connect with ssl enabled and https but it tries to connect with http and failed

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.client.rest.uris= https://localhost:9200
    spring.data.elasticsearch.client.rest.username= elastic
    spring.data.elasticsearch.client.rest.password= aZKfEj-Y8nWuCTFD-S54
    spring.data.elasticsearch.client.rest.ssl= true
    spring.data.elasticsearch.client.rest.trust-store= "...truststore.p12"
    spring.data.elasticsearch.client.rest.trust-store-password= password
```

my application.properties

Main method class

```
    package com.example.demo;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    @SpringBootApplication

    public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    }
```

ESConfig class

```
   package com.example.demo;

    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.EnableElasticsearchRepositories;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.demo")
    @Component
    @Configuration
    public class ElasticSConfig {

    }
```

controller

```
    package com.example.demo;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Optional;

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/products")
    public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @PostMapping
    public Product save(@RequestBody Product product) {
        return productRepository.save(product);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Optional<Product> findById(@PathVariable String id) {
        return productRepository.findById(id);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public Iterable<Product> findAll() {
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping(params = "name")
    public List<Product> findByName(@RequestParam String name) {
        return productRepository.findByName(name);
    }

    }
```

repository

```
package com.example.demo;

    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    import java.util.List;

    @Repository
    public interface ProductRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Product, String> {

    List<Product> findByName(String name);

    }
```

pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-    instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    </project>
```

Comment: Spring Data Elasticsearch does not read or process any properties from configuration files. This is a Spring Boot question